# Can I store a composable function in a variable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In Kotlin, function is a first-class citizen. We can store a function in a variable as below

```
val functionVariable: () -> Unit = ::myFunction

fun myFunction() { }
```

However, for `@Composable` function, how can I do so?

If I did the below, it will cry foul i.e. `org.jetbrains.kotlin.diagnostics.SimpleDiagnostic@e93b05f8 (error: could not render message)`

```
val functionVariable: () -> Unit = ::myFunction

@Composable
fun myFunction() { }
```

Is there a way to store composable function as a variable?

Comment: Not sure about your question. Try for example: `val button = Button(onClick = {}){Text("Button 1")}`

Comment: You might want to explain in greater detail what "it will cry foul" means.

Comment: I tried `val button = Button(onClick = {}){Text("Button 1")}` but it is not working. Anyway, I'm actually planning to store into a function variable, so that I can have a more dynamic composable function (e.g. store into a `var` instead of a `val`)... Just like a normal function, we can store in a variable, and then call `function.invoke()` when we to trigger it.

Comment: I have added detail on the error message @CommonsWare

Comment: The Compose Kotlin compiler plugin has limitations. You are seeing the limitation on [function references](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149424759). There are similar limitations on [lambda expressions](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142809384), [local functions](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169471826), and [reflection](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157590194). All but the reflection one are probably blocked by [this Kotlin issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34900).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Composable function reference is not yet supported (and that's what the error message actually is). Besides, `@Composable` annotation is part of the function signature because it adds some parameters to the function. So you need to use `val functionVariable: @Composable () -> Unit = { myFunction() }`.

Answer (score 5):

You can declare a composable function variable, like:

```
var functionVariable: @Composable () -> Unit = {}
```

Later you can reassign it (essentially redefining it) like:

```
functionVariable = { myFunction1() }
```

or

```
functionVariable = { myFunction2() }
```

But if you have functionVariable already planted in your larger Composable, the reassignment likely won't trigger recomposation.  What I do is declare a state variable like:

```
var functionAssigned by mutableStateOf(0)
```

And in you larger Composable where you plant functionVariable, do:

```
if (functionAssigned >= 0) functionVariable()
```

And whenever you want to reassign the variable, do:

```
functionVariable = { myFunction2() }
functionAssigned++
```

That will trigger needed recomposation.